# Why am I missing /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Libraries/libjawt.dylib on MacOSX?

Tags: java, macos, jogl, java-3d

I have been trying to install Java3D 1.5.2 on my Mac (OS 10.10). First I tried using the installer referenced in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12790031/2093695) by [whiskeyspider](https://stackoverflow.com/users/185322/whiskeyspider). It installed the files, but I got an error when I tried to run a program. So I cleared out /Library/Java/Extensions and tried to install manually in ~/.local/lib, a directory I created previously, and just include the jars in my project's build path (Eclipse). Despite including the jars and native library locations (for the JOGL jars) I get the following error when I try to run the program:

```
Exception in thread "J3D-Renderer-1" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/brianmc7/.local/lib/jogl/lib/libjogl_awt.jnilib: dlopen(/Users/brianmc7/.local/lib/jogl/lib/libjogl_awt.jnilib, 1): Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Libraries/libjawt.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/brianmc7/.local/lib/jogl/lib/libjogl_awt.jnilib
  Reason: image not found
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1929)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1851)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1119)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:189)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.NativeLibLoader.access$000(NativeLibLoader.java:49)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.NativeLibLoader$DefaultAction.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:80)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:103)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.NativeLibLoader.access$200(NativeLibLoader.java:49)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.NativeLibLoader$2.run(NativeLibLoader.java:132)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.NativeLibLoader.loadAWTImpl(NativeLibLoader.java:118)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.JAWT.getJAWT(JAWT.java:91)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.macosx.MacOSXOnscreenGLDrawable.lockSurface(MacOSXOnscreenGLDrawable.java:144)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.macosx.MacOSXOnscreenGLContext.makeCurrentImpl(MacOSXOnscreenGLContext.java:57)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.GLContextImpl.makeCurrent(GLContextImpl.java:134)
    at javax.media.j3d.JoglPipeline$QueryCanvas.doQuery(JoglPipeline.java:9049)
    at javax.media.j3d.JoglPipeline.getBestConfiguration(JoglPipeline.java:8797)
    at javax.media.j3d.Renderer.doWork(Renderer.java:514)
    at javax.media.j3d.J3dThread.run(J3dThread.java:275)
```

It turns out that the directory /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Libraries/ doesn't exist. How can I fix this problem?

**EDIT**: I should probably also mention that I am using JDK 1.8.0_40 early access.

Comment: Rather follow these instructions instead of using an obsolete version of Java3D: http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Downloading_and_installing_Java3D

Comment: Thanks, @gouessej, it worked! Are you sure 1.5.x is "obsolete," though? When I run my program with 1.6 I see `3D [dev] 1.6.0-pre11-daily-experimental daily` printed to stderr, suggesting that (as I have read elsewhere) 1.6.x is pre-release. Also, I found [the site they linked to](https://gouessej.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/java-3d-est-de-retour-java-3d-is-back/) more helpful, especially as it says which jars to import into Eclipse. But, if you expand your comment into an answer, I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java3D was [abandoned by Sun Microsystems / Oracle in 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_3D#cite_note-1). Java3D has been maintained by the JogAmp community since 2012. Yes, Java3D 1.6 is composed of several pre-releases but they work much better than Java3D 1.5.

[My own tutorial](https://gouessej.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/java-3d-est-de-retour-java-3d-is-back/) explains in details how to install the very latest version of Java3D.